# Can you use a class object as property in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have three models in my Django application - simplified for demonstration. The first one is Base. The second one is Bill and has foreign key "base" to Base model. The third one is Point, and has a foreign key to Bill.

```
class Base(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField()
    desc = models.IntegerField()

class Bill(models.Model):
    base = models.ForeignKey("Base", related_name="bills")
    total_value = models.DecimalField()

class Point(models.Model):
    bill = models.ForeignKey("Bill", related_name="points")
    value = models.DecimalField()
```

My goal is to have a property for Base called `def bill(self)`, that would sum up all "bill" objects fields and returned a bill-like instance. I would like to get a base object:

```
my_base = Base.objects.get()
bill = Base.bill     <-- I can figure this out with @property
points = bill.points <-- this does not work through @property function.
```

My current solution is like this, to get the first part working:

```
class Base():
    ...
    @property
    def bill(self):
       sums = self.bills.aggregate(total_value=Sum('total_value'))
       return Bill(**sums)
```

The second part, that would sum up bill-related-points and return them in a my_base.bill.points, does not work. If I filter for points and try to assign them to `Bill(**sums).points = filtered_points`, I get an error: *Direct assignment to the reverse side is prohibited*, or *Unsaved model instance cannot be used in an ORM query*

Is there a more elegant solution to this? A good option would be to initate class as a @property like so:

```
class Base(model.Model):
   ...
   class bill(...):
       self.total_value = .
       self.points = .
```

but I don't believe that is achievable.

Thank you

Comment: An aggregation of `Bill` instances containing a set of `Point` instances doesn't make much sense. Why not just have two properties?

Comment: Look just make another property. Like Aziz said